# Displaying size in JTextbox based on size of dynamic circle

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm trying to create a Java program that draws a circle, sliders can resize the circle, 3 other sliders control RGB settings.  The problem is that i cannot get the stats (diameter, area and circumference) to display in the JTextBox.  Please help its driving me mad!!!

Thanks!

CircleModifier.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CircleModifier extends JFrame implements ChangeListener {
   public DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

   public InfoPanel infoPanel;
   public JPanel sizePanel;

   private JPanel sliderPanel;
   private JSlider sizeSlider, redColorSlider, greenColorSlider,
         blueColorSlider;
   private JLabel sizeLabel, redLabel, greenLabel, blueLabel;

   public CircleModifier() {
      super("Circle Modifier Application");
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
      add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      sliderPanel = new JPanel();
      add(sliderPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
      sliderPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

      infoPanel = new InfoPanel();
      add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      sliderPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 4, 0, 1));
      sizeLabel = new JLabel("-Size-");
      sizeLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
      setSizeSlider(new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, 350, 10));
      getSizeSlider().setMajorTickSpacing(50);
      getSizeSlider().setMinorTickSpacing(25);
      getSizeSlider().setPaintTicks(true);
      getSizeSlider().setPaintLabels(true);
      getSizeSlider().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      getSizeSlider().addChangeListener(this);
      redColorSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, 255, 0);
      redColorSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
      redColorSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
      redColorSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
      redColorSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
      redColorSlider.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      redColorSlider.addChangeListener(this);
      redLabel = new JLabel("-Red-");
      redLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
      greenColorSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, 255, 0);
      greenColorSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
      greenColorSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
      greenColorSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
      greenColorSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
      greenColorSlider.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      greenColorSlider.addChangeListener(this);
      greenLabel = new JLabel("-Green-");
      greenLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
      blueColorSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, 255, 0);
      blueColorSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
      blueColorSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
      blueColorSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
      blueColorSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
      blueColorSlider.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      blueColorSlider.addChangeListener(this);
      blueLabel = new JLabel("-Blue-");
      blueLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

      sliderPanel.add(sizeLabel);

      sliderPanel.add(redLabel);
      sliderPanel.add(greenLabel);
      sliderPanel.add(blueLabel);

      sliderPanel.add(getSizeSlider());
      sliderPanel.add(redColorSlider);
      sliderPanel.add(greenColorSlider);
      sliderPanel.add(blueColorSlider);
      setSize(800, 500);

      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setVisible(true);
   }

   public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
      int size = getSizeSlider().getValue();
      drawingPanel.setDiameter(size);
      sizeLabel.setText("-Size-");
      int red = redColorSlider.getValue();
      int green = greenColorSlider.getValue();
      int blue = blueColorSlider.getValue();
      drawingPanel.setNewCircleColor(red, green, blue);
      redLabel.setText("-Red-");
      greenLabel.setText("-Green-");
      blueLabel.setText("-Blue-");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new CircleModifier();
   }

   public JSlider getSizeSlider() {
      return sizeSlider;
   }

   public void setSizeSlider(JSlider sizeSlider) {
      this.sizeSlider = sizeSlider;
   }
}
```

InfoPane.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class InfoPanel extends JPanel {
   JTextArea textarea;
   JLabel label;
   private JTextArea display;

   public InfoPanel() {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      label = new JLabel("Information");
      add(label);
      display = new JTextArea(5, 30);
      display.setText("The Radius is: " + "\nThe Diameter is: "
            + "Dynamic diameter to display here!" + "\nThe Area is: "
            + "\nThe Circumference is: ");
      add(display);
   }
}
```

DrawingPanel.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

   public static String size;
   int diameter = 1;
   int red = 255, green = 255, blue = 255;
   Color newCircleColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
      g.setColor(newCircleColor);
      g.fillOval(10, 10, diameter, diameter);
   }

   public void setDiameter(int newSize) {
      diameter = newSize;
      repaint();
   }

   public void setNewCircleColor(int red, int green, int blue) {
      newCircleColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
      repaint();
   }

}
```

Comment: Your code as formatted is very difficult to read, making it difficult to understand and thus making your question difficult to answer.. Please consider editing your post and fixing your indentation style so that it is uniform and consistent. I usually avoid using tabs for indenting (the site software often doesn't play well with tabs) and indent each code block 3  or 4 spaces (be consistent though).

Comment: Also, please less unnecessary empty lines. One empty line is plenty.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... Any idea how I can get the info box to display the stats?

Comment: I can't read your code yet, and my Eclipse has not yet loaded, so no. Again, if you want prompt help **please** fix your code.

Comment: Also, you've got two InfoPanels classes posted.

Comment: I've attempted to correct your code formatting. Now to look at it...

Answer (score 1):

Give InfoPanel a public method,

```
public void textareaSetText(String text) {
    textarea.setText(text);
}
```

And inside of this, set the text of the JTextArea variable.

Then call this method from within CircleModifier's `stateChanged(...)` method. If you want to append text, you could also give InfoPanel a similar `textareaAppendText(String text)` method.

Comment: @CharlyBear: try to implement it, and then if it fails, show us your attempt.

Comment: Also, if you don't understand something, try to let us know exactly what it is you don't understand, else it will be hard to help. I've shown you the code for the method, you surely know how to call a method within another method, so... where are you stuck??

Comment: Where inside the InfoPanel class do I place the code that you showed me? How do I set the JTextArea variable?

Comment: PS greatly appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Trying but no joy with this

Comment: @CharlyBear: Update your question with your attempt please. Show your latest code.  But please don't re-ask your same question using a new identity. That is not being fair to the volunteers who try to help on this site.

Comment: Well spotted.  My latest code is a mess! Trying to implement your suggestions but my Java skills are not up to the challenge!

Comment: @CharlyBear: Again, please show your attempts to implement my suggestions here as an edit to your original question. And again if you have any specific questions, please ask them, the  more specific, the better.

Comment: I've deleted the duplicate

Comment: @CharlyBear: thanks. Please now edit your original question, and let's see what's not working for you.

Comment: Any other hints? I have nothing worth posting to the original question unfortunately.. no progress but alot of trying... missing some of the basics

Comment: @CharlyBear: you need to learn basics before you can start coding, we can't put that knowledge into your head. As you're finding out, you won't understand our advice if you're not clear on your Java basics first. You're still going to have to ask specific questions. I'm not going to write the code for you, and neither should anyone else.